# Early 90s Sci-Fi Anthology series

Tags: story-identification, tv, episode-identification

I have been wracking my brain for years trying to remember the name of a very good Sci-Fi Anthology series from - I think - the early 90s. I'd always thought the two episodes I most vividly recall were from the new Outer Limits but having read through all the synopsis notes, I now know that probably wasn't it. Nor does it seem to have been any other similar listed show on Wikipedia. It was American (or Canadian) and was shown here in the UK on either Sky or BBC2.

The two episodes I most remember are one where a young man controls a commune of young women who are irresistibly attracted to him through his raised levels of testosterone (?). A small team of scientists send their female colleague into the commune to try and break the spell.

The other episode has an alien invasion force attacking Earth. Strange things start happening like entire communities disappearing. Earth defences ultimately make a mistake is shooting down what it thinks is the sole alien craft, because at the end of the episode, we suddenly see many more craft descending to Earth in impossible numbers.

I don't know which season/s of this show these stories come from.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthology_series#Science_fiction_and_horror

Comment: A story about women being irresistibly attracted to a man? Perhaps you stumbled across a copy of my autobiography...

Answer (score 2):

I think it actually is the Outer Limits (1995 version). Based on your 2 episode recollections (I think your 2nd is actually 2 combined episodes) I found these overviews.

Season 4 Episode 17 "[Lithia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithia_(The_Outer_Limits))" deals with an all female commune where males were wiped out due to a virus, and one cryogenically frozen male is woken up. This might be your first recollection

Season 4 Episode 6 "[Relativity Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_Theory_(The_Outer_Limits))" has a misunderstanding where an Earthling team kills a group of aliens, who were basically on a boy scout troop, and the alien parents return to earth in large numbers to attack.

Season 2 Episode 9 "[Trial by Fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Outer_Limits_(1995_TV_series)_episodes)" The President orders an attack on an alien advance scout thinking it was the beginning of an attack, but it's really a peace messenger. This might also be your recollection of the second point.